# Please identify a comic strip in mid 70's about astronaut who crashes on Mars and rebuilt by them

Tags: story-identification, comics, mars

I remember a short comic strip in the back of (I think) a DC monthly which depicted an astronaut who crashes on Mars (I think) and is tended to and fixed by the Martians. He subsequently is returned to Earth and in the last panel it's revealed the Martians didn't know what a human looked like, so he's disfigured horribly.

Any ideas what this was and where I can find it? I loved the idea as a kid and would love to own it again.

Comment: Have you tried checking out Strange Adventures? That sounds like a story from that title. Dc Comics from 1950-1973

Comment: I dont have a definite issue or story but the basis of that comic is science fiction / space/ horror (such as astronauts encountering martians), it was an anthology series that Gil Kane, Alex Toth, Carmine Infantino all worked on.  Just a suggestion to investigate that title.

Comment: This may have been an EC story, I remember it myself and the pilot was pretty disfigured, making it something of a horror story.